# Looking for an image viewer that lets you add custom descriptions under images

Tags: image-viewer, software

I am looking for an offline image viewing program that lets you organize photos in galleries, and add an extensive description to each image. Ideally, I would like the description to be displayed prominently under the image, similar to photo sharing websites like Flickr and DeviantArt (see example photo).

I am also open to software that imports photos into a type of text file describing the photo, although I would still like to be able to view these text files in a gallery with previews of their associated photos used as thumbnails.

Any help pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated!
[image: example]

Comment: Hello, define "extensive"